# Procedimiento almacenado para guardar información desde un FTP

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedure

Recién empiezo con el tema de procedimientos almacenados en SQL Server, en esta ocasión requiero extraer el nombre de la imagen y almacenarlo en una tabla, la tabla en la cual debo almacenar su nombre es el siguiente:

```
CREATE TABLE TBL_FOTOS (
    ID INTEGER IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    NOMBRE VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
)
```

La información de las imágenes se encuentran en un repositorio remoto.

El procedimiento almacenado lo llevo de esta manera:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_FOTOS]

AS
-- VARIABLE --
DECLARE 
    

BEGIN
    Select '\\192.***.**.**\Imagenes\'

    INSERT INTO TBL_FOTOS VALUE ('ID','NOMBRE')
    
END;
```

Con lo que tengo en mi Script ahora aun no logro almacenar dicha información de la imagen en la BD, lo unico que deseo almacenar es el nombre de la foto en la BD, creo que la manera mas facil es haciéndolo por medio de procedimiento almacenado, si alguien tiene alguna recomendación que me pueda hacer con gusto la recibiré.

Answer (score 1):

No parece el camino correcto. Sql server no es quién debería de llegar al repositorio remoto, sino, el código de tú lenguaje de programación, bien sea cliente o servidor. Aún así, caso de ser necesario, a priori, lo más lógico parece no cerrar el procedimiento a una ruta explicita.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_FOTOS]
( @nameImage varchar(256))

AS
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO TBL_FOTOS (NOMBRE)
    VALUES (@nameImage);
    
END;
```

Siendo tú procedure, el que recibe el nombre de la imagen, el encargado de insertarla en la tabla.

Ahora tu lenguaje (sea cual sea), que se conecta al ftp, llamará al procedure de un modo similar a:

```
Exec dbo.sp_fotos @nameImage = 'nombreImagen.jpg';
-- o
Exec dbo.sp_fotos 'nombreImagen.jpg';
```

Si lo realizas con sql server del modo que sea, siempre puedes alimentar una variable antes de llamar al procedure.

```
declare @mivar varchar(256);
set @mivar = (Select '\\192.***.**.**\Imagenes\'); -- aquí el código que fuese a obtener el nombre. 

Exec dbo.sp_fotos @mivar;
```

No obstante ese '\192.***.**.**\Imagenes' actualmente no es mas que un texto.

Por otro lado, cuando tienes una tabla que tiene un campo con la propiedad identity, no se menciona en la insert. El motor solo, ya sabe que tiene que insertar ese valor, salvo que establezcas [Set identity Insert](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/statements/set-identity-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 0):

Creo que la sintaxis de tu procedimiento sería algo como:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_FOTOS]

AS
-- VARIABLE --
DECLARE 
 
 Select '\\192.***.**.**\Imagenes\'

INSERT INTO TBL_FOTOS (id, campodelNombre) VALUES ('ID','NOMBRE')
```